# Can't seem to set the color or remove status bar in UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: objective-c, pdf

I'm trying to use UIDocumentInteractionController to show a PDF with a TOS and Privacy policy in my app.  I either want to change the color of the status bar to match my nav bar color or I want to remove the status bar.  I'm able to remove it but it leaves the 20pt spacing for it still.  I'm thinking I'm unable to make this work because UIDocumentInteractionController inherits from NSObject not UIViewController, and loads some second UIViewController which one can't get access to.  Ideas?  Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontrollerdelegate/1616799-documentinteractioncontrollervie?language=objc)

In short: if you return your navigation controller in that method the preview should respect the navigation/status bar style you are creating